# External variable access when chaining Promises

Tags: promise, chaining

I have a big problem in JS.

I have a function where I make a promise chain. A promise is "added" to the last promise in a for loop. Inside this loop there are some variables. Each function of each `then` needs to access these variables, that is, their values corresponding to the correct for iteration.

The problem is, I believe, since the promise is executed when the functions ends, each promise will read the same values of those variables (which have the values of the last for iteration).

I don't want this to happen. How can I do to solve it?

I have written a code that mimics my problem:

```js
function test() {
var p = Promise.resolve();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 var j = i * 10;
 p = p.then(function() {
  alert(j);
 });
}
  
p.then(function() {
 alert('finished');
})

}

test();
```

As you can see, each time the function inside then fires, it always reads value 90 of j, instead of reading all the correct values.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your first promise`p` will execute only after the whole for loop completes just because promises are aynchronous and the for loop is synchronous.. At the time the for loop completes `j` has already got assigned to 90. `Alert(j)` is just showing a message with only one content.. `j`. So all you get is 90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var` to `let` and then each invocation of the loop will have its own set of variables.

```js
function test() {
    let p = Promise.resolve();
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     let j = i * 10;
     p = p.then(function() {
      console.log(j);
     });
    }
      
    p.then(function() {
     console.log('finished');
    })
}

test();
```

`let` is block scoped so each block (in this case each iteration of the `for` loop) gets its own version of the `i` and `j` variables.  So, when you do your `alert(j)`, it will be using the correct variable.

FYI, I changed `alert(j)` to `console.log(j)` because using `alert()` can mess with asynchronous timing (since it blocks JS execution) whereas `console.log()` just reports and lets the code keep running so you get a better picture of how things actually run with `console.log()`.